# Problems by filtering and ordering with Spring JPA, Hibernate and Oracle

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle11g

I have the following entities **Label**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CNT_LBL_LABELS")
public class Label {
    ......

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
        name = "RSR_TAG_ENTITY",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID")
    )
    @WhereJoinTable(clause="ENTITY_TYPE='mypackage.Label'")
    @SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO rsr_tag_entity (entity_id, tag_id, entity_type) VALUES (?, ?, 'mypackage.Label')")
    @SQLDelete(sql = "DELETE FROM rsr_tag_entity WHERE entity_id=? AND tag_id=? AND entity_type='mypackage.Label'")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    protected Collection<Tag> tags;
    
    .......
}
```

and **Tag**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RSR_TAGS")
public class Tag {
    .......
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    protected Collection<Label> labels;
    
    .......
}
```

I need to retrieve one page of labels by possibly filtering and/or ordering by tags.
For this scope I'm using a custom executor that extends spring **PagingAndSortingRepository** and **JpaSpecificationExecutor**.

When I run the *list* method by sorting by tag I have the following SQL (I anonymized the entities properties by purpose):

```
select * from ( select label0_.* 
from cnt_lbl_labels label0_ 
left outer join rsr_tag_entity tags1_ on label0_.id=tags1_.entity_id and ( tags1_.ENTITY_TYPE='mypackage.Label')  
left outer join rsr_tags tag2_ on tags1_.tag_id=tag2_.id 
order by tag2_.tag_name desc, label0_.id asc ) where rownum <= ?
```

which works well.

Moreover, when I apply filtering to tag, without sorting, I have the following SQL:

```
select * from ( select distinct label0_.*
from cnt_lbl_labels label0_ 
left outer join rsr_tag_entity tags1_ on label0_.id=tags1_.entity_id and ( tags1_.ENTITY_TYPE='mypackage.Label')  
left outer join rsr_tags tag2_ on tags1_.tag_id=tag2_.id 
where (tag2_.uuid in ('TAG_UUID'))
order by label0_.id asc ) where rownum <= ?
```

which also works well.

Problems come when I try to filter and order by tag properties:

```
select * from ( select distinct label0_.*
from cnt_lbl_labels label0_ 
left outer join rsr_tag_entity tags1_ on label0_.id=tags1_.entity_id and ( tags1_.ENTITY_TYPE='mypackage.Label')  
left outer join rsr_tags tag2_ on tags1_.tag_id=tag2_.id 
where (tag2_.uuid in ('TAG_UUID'))
order by tag2_.tag_name desc, label0_.id asc ) where rownum <= ?
```

which causes the **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression** error.
This happens because we have the *distinct* keyword and the *tag2_.tag_name* is not among retrieved fields.

So, I tried to fetch join the Tag in the specification by
`root.fetch("tags", JoinType.LEFT);`

and I have the following error:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.tags] of basic type**.
In this case the SQL is not even created/logged.

I gave another try by fetching by INNER mode (the *null.tags* made me think about that was the cause)
and the produced SQL is now:

```
select distinct label0_.*,
tag4_.*, 
tags3_.entity_id as entity_id1_26_0__, 
tags3_.tag_id as tag_id2_26_0__ 
from cnt_lbl_labels label0_ 
left outer join rsr_tag_entity tags1_ on label0_.id=tags1_.entity_id and ( tags1_.ENTITY_TYPE='mypackage.Label')  
left outer join rsr_tags tag2_ on tags1_.tag_id=tag2_.id 
inner join rsr_tag_entity tags3_ on label0_.id=tags3_.entity_id and ( tags3_.ENTITY_TYPE='mypackage.Label')  
inner join rsr_tags tag4_ on tags3_.tag_id=tag4_.id 
where (tag2_.uuid in ('TAG_UUID'))
order by tag2_.tag_name desc, label0_.id asc
```

which still doesn't work because it's ordering by *tag2_.tag_name* instead of *tag4* which is retrieved.
I also tried to put *query.distinct(false)* in the specification, combined with LEFT and INNER jointype but nothing changed.

In any case I can't fetch by INNER mode as I need all labels apart from their tags.

Any suggestion to help me to solve this issue is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `DISTINCT` and then trying to `ORDER BY` a column that is not is in the `SELECT`ed columns that have had the `DISTINCT` operator applied to them.

You can filter the rows using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function rather than `DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         column1,
         column2,
         /* ..., */
         columnN
  FROM   (
    SELECT label0_.*,
           tag2_.tag_name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY
               label0_.id,
               label0_.column1,
               label0_.column2,
               /* ... */
               label0_.columnN
             ORDER BY ROWNUM
           ) AS duplicate_index
    FROM   cnt_lbl_labels label0_ 
           left outer join rsr_tag_entity tags1_
           on label0_.id=tags1_.entity_id
              and tags1_.ENTITY_TYPE='mypackage.Label'
           left outer join rsr_tags tag2_
           on tags1_.tag_id=tag2_.id 
    WHERE  tag2_.uuid IN ('TAG_UUID')
  )
  WHERE  duplicate_index = 1
  ORDER BY 
         tag_name desc,
         id asc
)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 5
```

*Note: `WHERE tag2_.uuid IN ('TAG_UUID')` will convert the `JOIN` for `tag2_` from a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` as it is impossible for outer-joined rows to match the `WHERE` filter. If you want it to be an `OUTER JOIN` then the `tag2_.uuid IN ('TAG_UUID')` filter needs to be in the `ON` clause of the join and not in the `WHERE` clause.*

Comment: You might not have red well the question. 
I know which is the cause (I've also specified in the question) but I don't have any control on the SQL because it's generated by Hibernate. The proposed solution should be related to JPA, not to SQL.

Comment: @Corzar This is an answer because it explains (1) why the SQL generated by your code is generating the error; (2) how the SQL could be fixed so that it does not generate the error. However, you are also correct that it is only a partial answer because it is not in JPA but then a JPA expert can use this solution to reverse engineer the necessary code for you (or you could do that) or tell you that it is not possible to use JPA annotations to solve this problem and you will have to use something like `@Query` and specify the SQL as above.